# C standard library with /clr:pure

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

As I understand, it is possible to compile C code that use C standard library with Visual C++ in clr:pure mode. What library is used for that?

- Is this a pure CLR library that translates C functions to approriate .NET or simply a bridge to unmanaged CRT?
- Is it possible to use such assembly on Linux with Mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is a bridge to unmanaged code.  Pure means that the compiler doesn't generate unmanaged code.  But it still generates calls to unmanaged code.  `/clr:safe` is even stronger.
2. It should work on Mono if you have Wine and the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime DLLs installed.